# How to make Circle color light in the Android google map

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

Below is my code where I am drawing circle on the Google Map in Android. It is working fine for me.

**Problem Statement:-**

Currently the circle that is getting drawn on the google map is very dark. I need to make that circle `little bit light with the same color` that I am having currently. Is that possible to make that circle little bit light by tweaking few parameters in the paint or color? It is more darker in the center part, don't know why. I just need to make it light in all the four circles that I have currently.

```
   class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames=new int[6];
    private Point mScreenPoints;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;


    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0]=currentUser;
        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]);
        mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (pointToDraw == null) {
            return true;
        }
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);
        int totalCircle=5;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=35;
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint); 
        } 
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (mScreenPoints.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(mScreenPoints.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Snapshot of my Circle currently[image]-

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

The reason why it gets darker in the center, is because you are drawing four circles, one over the other. When you draw the second circle, the part that is commoun to both, is painted twice, so it becomes darker. When you draw the tird circle, it becomes even darker ...

**Solution**

If you want all circles with same color, you should use `Style.STROKE` for all the circles, except the larger one, which shoud use `Style.FILL_AND_STROKE`. With that you only draw the lines for the small circles and fill all area when drawing the big one.

**Code**

```
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle-1; i ++) {  
        canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint);  
    }  
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
    canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, totalCircle*radius, mCirclePaint);
```

Regards